# Analytical Geometry General Help

Tags: analytic-geometry

In school, I'm learning about analytical geometry and all and I had a question...

Would it be possible to move up $X$ number of units upward along a slope.
You are given slope, you are given a point, and you are given a distance to go up from that point. I've seen many solutions to this but is there a formula? or method you like to use?

Eg.

Move $10$ units up from point $(4, 3)$, slope is $y = -\dfrac{4}{3} x + \dfrac{25}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The point you are searching is one of the intersections between the line  $y = -\dfrac{4}{3} x + \dfrac{25}{3}$ and the circle with center $C=(4,3)$ and radius $10$. Do you know how to find it?

Comment: With systems of equations yes, but isn't there a more efficient method? Thanks for formatting my question above by the way :). @Emilio Novati

Comment: not sure whether to put a space or not...